# Applying str() explicitly vs allowing Django to do it itself yields different results in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Given a template `{{ foo }} {{ bar }}` and a context `{'foo': Decimal('12.34'), 'bar': str(Decimal('12.34'))}`, the template renders as `12,34 12.34`. Why are the results different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be Django doing [format localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/) for you. You can disable it by setting `USE_L10N` to `False` within your settings.

For your particular problem you could set the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` setting to a a dot instead of a comma, so in your settings it would be:

```
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
```

Comment: But how does it work exactly? Does it have some `if isinstance(value, Decimal):` clauses or what? I think the documentation stated something along the lines that it just converted any non-string value to a string. Also, disabling L10N globally doesn't feel like a good idea if the only thing I need is to output the value in a JavaScript-parseable way. Is there a filter for that or something? Creating a filter tag just containing the `str` call feels lame.

Comment: Yes, it does work by using `isinstance` [see here](http://git.io/Qm_eHg). There are other settings that you can use to fix your problem, you can see them [here](http://git.io/tldL_w).

Comment: Thank you! I've just found the [localize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#template-tags) tag which allows disabling l10n on a case-by-case basis. This seems to be a proper treat in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Because `foo` is a number (`Decimal` type) and is formatted according to the current localization of your application. In the language you set, the decimal separator is a comma.

On the other side, `bar` is a string, formatted by Python. When you apply `str` to a `Decimal`, the string representation does not take into account the localization of the Django project (because it is a Python methods and not related to Django) and returns the common *"English"* format, with a dot.

**Django can apply format localization only on numeric objects** (and also dates and times and other minors things), not plain string. It would be too heavy to analyse each string to check if there is a number and if it needs to be formatted...

[More information about Django localization in the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/).